# Can a public abstract class create an object of itself inside itself?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm learning the chain of responsibility pattern and this is given as the example:

```
abstract public class AbstractRequest {

    // Each request is identified by a an integer
    // FireRequest: 1
    // LowFuelRequest: 2
    private int requestCode;

    public AbstractRequest(int requestCode) {
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
    }

    public int getRequestCode() {
        return requestCode;
    }
}

abstract public class AbstractHandler {

    private AbstractHandler next;

    public AbstractHandler(AbstractHandler next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setNext(AbstractHandler next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void handleRequest(AbstractRequest request) {
        if (next != null) {
            next.handleRequest(request);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand how an abstract class can create an object.

Moreover, how can a class be instantiated inside itself?

Wouldn't it cause indefinite recursion?

EDIT:
The above questions are raised w.r.t this line:
 `private AbstractHandler next;`

Comment: Object creation in java is always done with the `new` keyword. As you can see there isn't a single `new` in the code above, hence absolutely no object creation is taking place anywhere in that code.

Comment: *"how can a class be instantiated inside itself?"* leaving aside the fact that no-one is instantiating anything here, [recursive data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type) exist in many languages, including java. That's how you define lists, for example.

Comment: Where do you think an object is created inside the abstract class?

Comment: I think he meant to ask "can a class have a field of the same type than itself?" (the class `AbstractHandler` has a field of type `AbstractHandler`, the first class is in the question but could not be there). And the answer is yes, it can.

Comment: "I can't understand how an abstract class can create an object." what makes you think they are? Note that variable of *supertype* can hold (reference to) object of *subtype*. For instance `Animal animal = new Cat();` (note that `Animal` may also be *abstract* class, while `Cat` is non-abstract subtype of `Animal`).

Answer (score 0):

In fact the following compiles (not written by me):

*A.java*

```
interface A {
    final A FOO = new B();
}
```

*B.java*

```
class B implements A {
}
```

This is because the .class files are like object files (.o, .obj) files in other languages, and the linkage is done with textual signatures. So A imports a class B, and B imports an interface A, without requiring them to be compiled already.

The ClassLoader of the JVM will then "link" them, possibly giver "link" errors, like method not available or such.